# Netflix's Daredevil & Marvel Movies - What order?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, suggested-order, daredevil, daredevil-2015

How does Netflix's Daredevil fit into this Marvel movie order?

- Captain America: The First Avenger
- Marvel One-Shot: Agent Carter (short; Iron Man 3 release)
- Iron Man
- The Incredible Hulk (campus rampage; overlaps w/ Iron Man 2)
- Iron Man 2
- Marvel One-Shot: A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to Thor's Hammer (short; Captain America release)
- Thor (reference to Hulks experiment; overlaps w/ Iron Man 2)
- Marvel One-Shot: The Consultant (short; Thor release)
- Captain America: The First Avenger (end of movie; post credits)
- The Avengers (aka "Avengers Assemble")
- Marvel One-Shot: Item 47 (short; Avengers release)
- Iron Man Three
- Marvel One-Shot: All Hail The King (short; Thor: The Dark World release)
- Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D Season 1, Pilot (ep. 1) to The Hub (ep. 7)
- Thor: The Dark World
- Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D Season 1, The Well (ep. 8) to End of the Beginning (ep. 16)
- Captain America: The Winter Soldier (runs simultaneously with S.H.I.E.L.D, ep. 16)
- Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D Season 1, Turn Turn Turn (ep. 17) to Beginning of the End (ep. 22)
- Guardians of the Galaxy
- Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D Season 2, Shadows (ep. 1) to Making Friends and Influencing People (ep. 3)

Comment: Right now, the other question/answers doesn't go over the Daredevil info as the exact timeframe of the show has not been revealed yet. [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45654/5184) to the question is kept up to date with internal chronological order.