# What's Loki been up to since Dark World?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

At the end of *Thor: The Dark World*, Loki

> fooled Thor and was sitting on Odin's Throne.

Have there been any hints or storylines on what schemes he is been running since?

Are there any new comics that are in par with the movies and can be used to find out what Loki is doing in the background while the Avengers are being kept busy?

Since infinity stones have been mentioned in *Guardians of the Galaxy* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron,* do the Avengers/Thor (and therefore Loki) universes meet with the Guardians of the Galaxy universe?

Comment: I'm going to leave open, since at this point, the answer is a legitimate "No; we haven't seen what he's been up to"...

Comment: No comics with to help guess the story line you mean ?

Comment: Unfortunately, even if there were comics referring to this part of the story, they still wouldn't be very helpful, since the story in your question doesn't take place in the comics.

Comment: FYI the universes wouldn't meet they are already one in the same. Any Marvel movie/tv show on this list is in the MCU already. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45654/22709

Comment: As shown in *Thor: Ragnarok*, it seems like he was just lazing around, creating plays to glorify himself, until Thor came back to snap him out of it as shown in that movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your *second* question is "Yes" - the Infinity Stones that appear in a [number of the Marvel Cinematic Universe movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Gems#Film) and the Guardians of the Galaxy universe is the same one as the other movies in this franchise. Marvel Studios representatives have said that the remaining stones will be introduced in the "phase 3" batch of movies [culminating in an "Infinity War" storyline](http://www.comicbookresources.com/article/feige-latcham-say-infinity-war-leads-to-the-end-of-the-avengers-as-we-know-them).